# How to find a record and N records before selected record in one query on PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like the below:

| id | name | date | last update |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test1 | 01-01-2021 | 5-01-2021 |
| 2 | test2 | 02-01-2021 | 6-01-2021 |
| 3 | test3 | 03-01-2021 | 6-01-2021 |
| 4 | test4 | 04-01-2021 |  |
| 5 | test5 | 05-01-2021 |  |

I want to make a query to receive the first record that "last update" = null and 2 records before it. The result should be:

| id | name | date | last update |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | test2 | 02-01-2021 | 6-01-2021 |
| 3 | test3 | 03-01-2021 | 6-01-2021 |
| 4 | test4 | 04-01-2021 |  |

Comment: Your example shows the first record with last_update = null. Is it first or last that you want?

Comment: @RichardHuxton the first record that the "last update" is null ( in my sample is test4 ) and  two records before ( test3 + test2)

Comment: @Shadi there is contradictions.
In Original Post , you said 
<quote>
make a query to receive the LAST  record that "last update" = NULL
<unqote>

And in reply to Richard , you said
<quote>
 the FIRST record that the "last update" is null
<unquote>
You are saying LAST in the original post and FIRST while answering the above question.
So, one of these needs rectified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look for the date that has the first NULL last_update.
Then get also the 2 before that date.

> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM
> (
>     SELECT * 
>     FROM your_table
>     WHERE date <= (
>       SELECT date  -- the date of the first NULL last_update
>       FROM your_table 
>       WHERE last_update IS NULL 
>       ORDER BY date ASC NULLS LAST
>       LIMIT 1
>     )
>     ORDER BY date DESC
>     LIMIT 1+2      -- the NULL last_update + 2 records before it
> ) q
> ORDER BY date ASC;
> ```

| id | name | date | last_update |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | test2 | 2021-01-02 | 2021-01-06 |
| 4 | test3 | 2021-01-03 | 2021-01-06 |
| 5 | test4 | 2021-01-04 | *null* |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=394265222f9a91325f9c1505b8e8a47b)*

Comment: Great, that's work. Just clarify, what is the `q`?

Comment: Just a short alias name for the sub-query. Some database flavors require it, so I got this habbit to add it. `q` is short for query.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
select * from yourTable where lastUpdate=(select Max(lastUpdate) from yourTable)
Union all 
select id,name,date,lastUpdate from 
    (select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by lastUpdate order by id)as rn from yourTable where lastUpdate is null )a where rn=1
```

Output:

```
id  name    date    lastUpdate
2   test2   2021-02-01  2021-06-01
3   test3   2021-03-01  2021-06-01
4   test4   2021-04-01  NULL
```

Comment: thanks I run this query but I received all records before the test in the sample. How can I limit for example two records?

Comment: This query will give a good answer for the data you provided. So in this case you have to provide a lot of data.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution using "with" statement as described [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/queries-with.html).

```sql
WITH dat AS 
  (SELECT ID FROM records WHERE last_update ISNULL ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1)   --Finding the first null

SELECT r.* 
FROM
    records r, dat 
WHERE
    r.ID BETWEEN ( dat.ID - 2 ) AND dat.ID                              --Finding 2 records before
ORDER BY r.ID;
```

Comment: Could you explain what is the "r"?